# Consume Cloud Run environment variables inside Nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js, google-cloud-run

I've recently built a Nextjs app, which I am hosting on Google Cloud Run.

My app makes some requests to external APIs from the `getStaticProps()` method.

I would like to be able to point to a different API host depending on the environment (e.g prod or dev) using environment variables which would be set differently for each environment.

I know I can store these variables in environment specific files like `.env.development` and `.env.production` however I would like to be able to store these environment variables in the environment variables field in the Google Cloud console for the cloud run service and skip storing them in the files altogether.

I have tried adding in the variables to Cloud Run, but it does not work. I have also tried prefixing the variables with NEXT_PUBLIC_... With no luck.

Did anyone have any tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Ok... I think I have figured it out now.
I was using Cloud Builds to build my container, and the container runs `npm run build` before it runs `npm run start`.

I assume that my Cloud Run variables aren't available at the point in time when Cloud Build is building the project.

So, I think my solution is prob to try and inject the variables at the point when it is building, using substitution variables.

EDIT: Confirmed. If I start Nextjs in dev mode, such that the page is rendered on the server for each request, then the Cloud Run environment variables are used.
To build the Nextjs app for production, I include the environment variables in the Dockerfile that is built by Cloud Build

EDIT: as request, an example of a dockerfile setting the environment variable:

```
FROM node:16.13-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY . /usr/src

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_API_HOST='https://some.host.com'

RUN npm install -only=production
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

Then you can just reference the environment variable from within your code using `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_API_HOST`

Comment: Could you please share an example file of envirorments in Dockerfile?

Comment: Hi Mike, can you please explain how did you solve this problem? It's driving me crazy...

Comment: @Pablopvsky, see edited answer above

Comment: @SamiulHSohan, so, *Cloud Run* Environment variables are actually available from within the nextjs app, however my mistake was to ignore the fact that when I am building the container for *Cloud Run*, I am not within the context of the *Cloud Run* application, since the container is actually built by *Cloud Build*. Remember that *getStaticProps()* is run at build time. In order to solve the issue, you will need to find a way to provide the variables to the application apart from *Cloud Run* env vars.

Comment: getStaticProps() run in build time but if you use de "revalidate", it take the Cloud Run variables.  `return {
    props: {
      preview,
      doc: doc?.allHomepages?.edges?.[0]?.node ?? null,
    },
    revalidate: 30, // In seconds
  };`

Comment: It works but then what about the security we  generally keep ENV in .env file and dont upload it to Git Repo. Here if we will place all the secret ENV variables in Dockerfile which must be pushed to repo then how will it stay secure?